# Issue in hiding focus styles when an html component is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am creating a input component. For better UX, I hide focus styles when the component is clicked (this I have done in handler for click event). But this is not working well in one scenario:

1. Click the component
2. Navigate away from browser tab (I am using chrome)
3. Come back to browser tab

As soon as you come back to the page focus event fires on element that was last focused but since click event has not got fired focus styling comes back. Something you did  not wanted.

Can someone plz suggest a good fix for this.

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS to remove/edit the style.

```
input:focus {
    box-shadow: none;
    outline: none;
}
```

Comment: I do not want to altogether hide focus style. I want to hide it just when component is clicked.

Comment: To be clear, you don't want focus style when an element is clicked, but you want focus style if it receives focus in other ways (e.g. tab, JS)? But you didn't want focus when it comes back from a browser tab (not a click), so what gives?